# How can I define a accuracy measure for word2vec predictions

Tags: accuracy, word-embeddings, word2vec, cosine-similarity, cosine-distance

I have a data set consisting of tags and some classes.I'm suppose to find the nearest class to each set of tags with Word2vec embeddings and cosine similarity.Each set of tags have multiple classes related to it which the model is supposed to predict so it's a multi-label classification.After giving the set of tags to my word2vec model(google news 3m) I find the closest classes based on cosine similarity to that set of tags.My question is how am i suppose to measure accuracy in this case because cosine similarity only tells how much the predicted classes are close to the tags.Can this be used as the model accuracy ? can i average the closeness of predicted classes to tags and use that as the final closeness of my prediction?
e.g :
model predictions:

[garden(similarity_to_tags=0.8),house(similarity_to_tags=0.5),other preds...]

labels:[garden,house]

accuracy =(0.8+0.5)/2